# How to specify celery beat periodic task?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I want to make a periodic task with Django and Celery. I have configured the celery in my project.

The **project structure** looks like this:

```
project
├── apps
│   ├── laws
│        └──tasks
│           └──periodic.py # the task is in this file
├── config
│   ├── celery.py
│   ├── settings
│      └── base.py # CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE defined in this file
```

**base.py**:

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "sample_task": {
        "task": "apps.laws.tasks.periodic.SampleTask", # the problem is in the line
        "schedule": crontab(minute="*/1"),
    },
}
```

**periodic.py**:

```
class SampleTask(Task):
    name="laws.sample_task"

    def run(self, operation, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.info("The sample task in running...")
```

Here is the error I get:

```
 The delivery info for this task is:
 {'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'celery'}
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 591, in on_task_received
     strategy = strategies[type_]
 KeyError: 'apps.laws.tasks.periodic.SampleTask'
```

**How can I define the route of the task correctly?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
instead of the route, just put the name of the task in settings:

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "laws.sample_task": {
        "task": "laws.sample_task", # put the name here.
        "schedule": crontab(minute="*/1"),
    },
}
```